# c++ operator overload question in an interview online test

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I recently saw an interview online test question that I need help with. This is not a question for a job I'm interviewing for, I was just curious about the answer. Thanks in advance.

```
 #include <iostream>
    class Foo
    {
        //...
    };

    void staff(Foo& f)
    {
        //..
        std::out << f << endl; // output Foo object f
    }
```

The question was:

What operators need to be defined in order to show object properly?

1. `std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&)` as a member function of class `Foo`
2. `std::streambuf& operator << (std::ostream&, Foo const&)` as a stand alone, overloaded operator.
3. `void << operator<<(std::ostream& , Foo const&)` as a stand alone, overloaded
4. `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, Foo const&)` as a stand alone, overloaded
5. `void std::operator<<(std::ostream&)` as a memeber function of class `Foo`

Comment: (comments out-of-hand; removed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, Foo const&);
```

You should define `operator<<` with the above signature.

Comment: I agree. And I don't know why the question was closed either.  It seems perfectly applicable to any C++ programmer.